# Dijkstra Traversal relationship property

Tags: java, neo4j, dijkstra, tree-traversal

Is it possible to search for the shortest path using Dijkstra from Node A to Node B by only passing nodes having a property x with a certain value? Is this also possible by taking a relationship property into account?

If yes, could you explain me how?

Thanks for letting me know something in any case.

Kind regards,
Johan,

Comment: I am curious as to why we have a sudden surge of dijkstra related questions here, I can't explain it. Note that this is just my curiosity that wants to be satisfied OP, your question is a fine one.

Comment: @arynaq That's probably because a number of universities have started new semesters and Dijkstra is typical for the beginning of a semester. Anyway how about just adding an if statement when you add the node to your queue and check if it satisfies the condition?

Answer (score 1):

Nodes that have a given property and the edges that connect them form a *subgraph* of the original. It's trivial to adapt Dijkstra's algorithm to work on a subgraph: just ignore the vertices and edges that don't belong.

Comment: @downvoter: what am I missing? Is there some subtlety that makes this answer wrong?